# Using PHP generated JSON in javascript : issues with backslashes

Tags: javascript, php, regex, json, backslash

I have seen a few relevant answers where a specific character in JSON string from PHP is converted to javascript friendly version.
With some help I have come this far :

- Javascript does not handle backslashes very well, infact these need to be replaced by double backslash.
- New line characters \r\n do not work well, either you need a carriage return or remove the symbols totally.
- double quotes in strings need escaping by 'double backslash' instead of single one.
- forward slash which appears escaped by backslash in paths does not need escaping.

example non-working json below (validated at jsonlint but fails in JSON.parse)

```
["string\r\n next line \"quoted text\" and \b at path \/var\/opt "]
```

I needed to convert to following after replacements to make it work

```
["string next line \\"quoted text\\" and \\b at path /var/opt "]
```

**The Problem**

My problem is that my json in php depends on user input and I don't know what they will put up. PHP will use the standard json conversion method and have its validation.

Like the above, are there any other scenarios I should be covering, specifically unicode , other special characters etc ?

**Update**

My json string is a bit more complex than this example and changes dynamically, a small example is

```
{ "settings.conf": [ "tooltip='dynamic unicode text multiline with \ or \\ or even \" etc '", "value=the value"]}
```

Im doing

```
var jstring = <?php sanitize_json(json_encode($source_array)); ?>

JSON.parse(jstring);
```

and my sanitize_json function is currently doing the backslash replacement and is working, however I want to include the newline characters \r\n. Also need to ensure there are no other issues of this kind with json in js.

Comment: "My problem is that my json in php depends on user input and I don't know what they will put up." Any input from the user should be sanitized before it is processed.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue a little more? Sorry, but I fail to grasp where your first string is wrong - it produces valid object (in JS). Is the issue that you allow users to craft their JSON, which is then saved to DB, which then you want to turn to JS object through JSON.parse?

Answer (score 2):

How do you feed your Json string into `JSON.parse`?

I ran into your issue by simply executing this javascript code:

```
JSON.parse('["string\r\n next line \"quoted text\" and \b at path \/var\/opt "]');
```

But the thing is: While the JSON string is valid, it has to be escaped in the context of being part of a javascript string. Every backslash that appears to be within the JSON string in fact is part of the javascript string - and a javascript string containing "\n" will convert this into a newline character. So the data that gets written to memory is not the text you see in the source code.

```
var x = '["string\\r\\n next line \\"quoted text\\" and \\b at path \\/var\\/opt "]';
alert(x); // should show the original JSON string
JSON.parse(x); // should work perfect then
```

So your problem just converted from "how do I create a valid JSON string in PHP" to "How do I properly put that correctly created JSON string (result of `json_encode()` in PHP) inside my Javascript code?"

And we need some more details from you here, because I would say that simply creating the variable from the JSON directly should work:

```
var x = ["string\r\n next line \"quoted text\" and \b at path \/var\/opt "];
```

instead of

```
var x = JSON.parse('["string\r\n next line \"quoted text\" and \b at path \/var\/opt "]');
```

Comment: My best guess is that OP might be using JSON.parse to determine if the entered JSON-string is correct (on the other hand he can use json_decode to do that). Overall though - nice write up.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `json_encode()` [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you will see there are various flags that you can set that will sanitise the data. In your case, `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` might do the trick:

`json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: A slash (your suggestion) is not a backslash (main component in the question).

Comment: I may be wrong, but in the context of the json constant that I mentioned, I am under the impression that a backslash is indeed a slash

Comment: Citing the JSON constants page: *"JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES (integer) 
 Don't escape /. Available since PHP 5.4.0."* This does not mention or include the backslash *"\"*

Comment: Acutally this works perfectly but im developing a plugin targetted towards PHP 5.2 onward. If it was PHP 5.4 onward and this would be the accepted answer.

Comment: In which case, you may need to write a function which mimics the action of `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and ensure you call it each time you encode. Good luck with your project.